# Remove all unnecessary libs from fat jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing java console application using Spring Boot Jpa and MySQL connector. How I can easily exclude all unnecessary libs from my fat jar?

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
//        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'ca.cutterslade.gradle:gradle-dependency-analyze:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'ca.cutterslade.analyze'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
    mysqlVersion = '6.0.6'
    hibernateVersion = '5.2.12.Final'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
//    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.12.Final'
//    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.2.12.Final'
//    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'
//    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
//    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.0-api', version: '1.0.0.Final'
//    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '4.3.13.RELEASE'
//    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '4.3.13.RELEASE'
//    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
//    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
//    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version: '2.5.4'
//    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.11.9.RELEASE'
//    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-test', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
//    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
//    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '4.3.13.RELEASE'



    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: mysqlVersion
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: hibernateVersion
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

jar {
    baseName 'ReportGenerator'
    version '1.0'
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried to use `gradle-dependency-analyze` and received the following result:

```
usedUndeclaredArtifacts: 
 - org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
 - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.9.RELEASE
 - org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.13.RELEASE
 - org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.13.RELEASE
 - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.9.RELEASE
 - org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
 - org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.13.RELEASE
 - org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.11.9.RELEASE
unusedDeclaredArtifacts: 
 - mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6
 - org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.12.Final
 - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.9.RELEASE
```

As you see `unused libraries` are marked all libraries in my gradle at the moment. And `required libraries`are marked only which are used in the scope of my classes in app but don't get me know what these required libraries depends on also. If I will put only these list of required dependencies in the gradle then I will get different initialization errors since some libraries are missed.

Comment: Since you should add only necessary dependencies anyways and those should only bring necessary transitive dependencies there shouldn't be that many "unnecessary" libs - if any. Of course if you only use part of a dependency there might be some "unnecessary" transitive dependencies (because you don't use the code that needs them) - is that what you mean, i.e. [tree shaking](http://tapasjena.com/all-about-tree-shaking/)?

Comment: You're right, I want to have in my jar only dependencies which was used by app functionality. But I cannot figure out what easy way to detect what libs are un-/necessary to exclude/stay.

Comment: I doubt that the analysis of "unused Artifacts" is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Couple of suggestions.

1. Use `dependency:analyze` on your project which will list the unused dependencies, which you can exclude or get rid of.
2. use the `<scope>` attribute for each and every dependency in your pom, which can greatly reduce your fat jar size. Provide correct scope parameters, like compile, test .....